# Can I use tag to take backup of a specific point?

Tags: git, github, version-control, backup

I need to take a backup at specific point in Github, as we are removing at least 50% of code now. What is the best way to handle this.

PS: We dont have plans to use the code we are removing even in future, but just wanted to keep it as backup.

Should I create a different branch or have a tag?

Thanks.

Comment: A tag is enough.

Comment: Yes, record the certain commit you want to backup with a tag. And the tag can helps you get the commit easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tag generally used for indicating a point where you are making a release. Suppose we have released v1.00, for keeping track our this release code we make a tag so that we can easily find out what were the codes at release v1.00. We can say Git tag track a particular commit in a branch.

We use branch for separating out main code(master branch) from our developing(dev branch) or testing(test branch) code. And finally we Marge them with main code(master branch).

So in your case, commit your latest changes to a branch and Tag it. 
Hope this will help you :-) .

Answer (score 1):

First, the purpose of a version control system can be summarized—perhaps overly summarized, but still—as: *Remember every version ever.*  So the fact that you're using a version control system means that you are *already* saving all your code, permanently, forever.  The problem that soon arises is that of any collector: *finding* something in the collection.  You need some kind of index, or catalogue, or whatever.

So think of it this way: *a tag remembers a commit.*

Commits, in Git, are those things you see that have big ugly hash IDs.  Here is a bit of one from a clone of the Git repository for Git itself:

```
$ git log
commit e3a80781f5932f5fea12a49eb06f3ade4ed8945c
Author: Junio C Hamano ...
```

That thing starting with `e3a80781f` is the commit's "true name".  This same commit will have this same number in *every copy* of this repository, and that number is reserved for *this* commit.  If you memorize it, you'll always be able to tell if a repository has this commit, and if a Git repository for Git and has this number in it, it's *this* commit.  (If a Git repository for Git *doesn't* have this commit, it's probably just out of date and needs a `git fetch` to bring it up to date.<sup>1</sup>)

But: who can remember this thing?  You might remember `e3a` or something like that but pretty soon it just breaks down into a jumble of hexadecimal digits.  So this is what tags are for.  Any *particularly interesting* commit can have a tag, or you can even make a special kind of tag, an *annotated* tag, that has extra information in it:

```
$ git show v2.16.2
tag v2.16.2
Tagger: Junio C Hamano ... [snippage]

commit ffa952497288d29d94b16675c6789ef83850def3
Author: Junio C Hamano ...
```

The name `v2.16.2` means something to a human.  It remembers the commit ID (which in this case is `ffa952497288d29d94b16675c6789ef83850def3`) in a way that *you* can remember.

Note that a branch name like `master` also remembers a (single) Git commit.  The key difference—at least here; there are a few more—between a branch name like `master` and a tag name like `v2.16.2` is that a branch name *changes* over time, to remember the *latest* commit on the branch.  A tag name doesn't.

Note that in Git, each commit records a *parent* commit.  This chain of *latest commit has a parent; the parent has its own parent (this commit's grandparent)* and so on forms the history of the software.  So the commits stored in the repository *are* the history.  Each commit holds a snapshot of the source, and that's how Git keeps every version ever.  The only time this doesn't hold up occurs if you use the tools that Git provides to *rewrite history*, as some put it: to make new commits that are back-dated, but disagree with the original commits, and then to change your saved names—your branch and tag names—so that they remember the new, rewritten history instead of the original history.

If you don't rewrite history and move the tags, you keep every version ever made.  Of course, your repository is just that—*yours*—so you *can* move the tags; it's just that this is not how they are *intended* to work.<sup>2</sup>  And remember: while your Git repository is *yours*, every clone of a Git repository is—at least by default, in the normal setups—a complete copy of all the history: all the commits.  So everyone—Alice, Bob, and Carol, for instance—has everything, or at least, Alice has everything the other Git had when Alice made her clone, Bob has everything the other Git had when Bob made his clone, and so on.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are a few other possibilities: a repository could be a *shallow* clone that deliberately omits some history, for instance.  In this case a simple `git fetch` won't fix it, but you can `git fetch --unshallow` to fill in all the history.  Another is, of course, a repository containing code *pretending* to be Git that isn't actually Git.  If it's maliciously pretending, Git's design makes it difficult for it: it probably won't have this commit, and it almost certainly won't have a PGP-signed annotated tag *endorsing* it, but that's a topic for a different question.

<sup>2</sup>If you do rewrite history, your *new* commits with the new history will have different commit hash IDs from the originals, so people will be able to tell.  In fact, they will generally find out even if they *don't* care to do so, because *their* Git can, and typically will, keep the original history while adding the new history, and show *both* of them.  But this, too, is another topic for a different question.